# What does this BlackBerry Web App Javascript code do?

Tags: javascript, mobile, blackberry

I know my way around several programming languages but am struggling understanding Javascript and how it's used in mobile apps. I'm developing for BlackBerry and a using the BlackBerry 10 jQuery Mobile Theme. I'm looking at the App.js from the samples and am confused as to what the App object is.

```
App = {};

App.init = function () {
    console.log("App Init");
    App.utils.metaHack();
    $("#activity").live("pageinit", function(){
        App.page.activity.init();
    });
    $("#bb_activity").live("pageinit", function(){
        App.page.bb_activity.init();
    });
    $("#progressPage").live("pageinit", function(){
        App.page.progress.init();
    });
    $("#sliderPage, #sliderPageDark").live("pageinit", function(){
        App.page.slider.init();
    });
    $("#togglePage, #togglePageDark").live("pageinit", function(){
        App.page.toggle.init();
    });
    $("#actionBarSample").live("pageinit", function() {
        App.page.actionBarSample.init();
    });
    $('#applicationMenu').live("pageinit", function() {
        App.page.applicationMenu.init();
    });
}

App.utils = {
    metaHack: function () {
        var meta = document.createElement("meta");
        meta.setAttribute('name','viewport');
        meta.setAttribute('content','initial-scale='+ (1/window.devicePixelRatio) + ',user-scalable=no');
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
    }
}

App.page = {
    activity: {},
    bb_activity: {},
    progress: {},
    slider: {},
    toggle: {},
    actionBarSample: {},
    applicationMenu: {}
}

App.page.activity.init = function() {
    $('#show').on('click', function () {
            $.mobile.loading('show');
    });
    $('#text').on('click', function() {
        $.mobile.loading('show', {
            text: 'Loading',
            textVisible: true,
            textonly: true,
            theme: 'a'
        });
    });
    $('#swatch-a').on('click', function() {
        $.mobile.loading( 'show', {
            text: 'Loading',
            textVisible: true,
            theme: 'a'
        });
    });
    $('#swatch-a-notext').on('click', function() {
        $.mobile.loading( 'show', {
            theme: 'a'
        });
    });
    $('#swatch-c').on('click', function() {
        $.mobile.loading( 'show', {
            text: 'Loading',
            textVisible: true,
            theme: 'c'
        });
    });
    $('#swatch-c-notext').on('click', function() {
        $.mobile.loading( 'show', {
            theme: 'c'
        });
    });
    $('#hide').on('click', function () {
        $.mobile.loading('hide');
    });
}

App.page.bb_activity.init = function() {
    console.log("bb_activity");
    $('#throttle').on('change', function () {
        console.log("throttle");
        var speed = $('#throttle').val();
        $('#speedTest').activityindicator('speed', speed+'s');
    });
}

App.page.progress.init = function() {
    var p = 0;
    var error = pause = false;

    function watchProgress() {
        if( p > 100 || error || pause) {
            return;
        }
        $('#rogress').progressbar("setValue", p);
        p+= 4;
        setTimeout(watchProgress, 100);
    }


    $('#start').on('vclick', function () {
        error = false;
        watchProgress();
    });

    $('#error').on('vclick', function () {
        $('#rogress').progressbar("setError", error = !error);
    });

    $('#pause').on('vclick', function () {
        $('#rogress').progressbar("pause", pause = !pause);
    });

    $('#reset').on('vclick', function () {
        p = 0;
        error = pause = false;
        $('#rogress').progressbar("setValue", p);
    });
}

App.page.slider.init = function() {
    $('#slider-disabled').slider('disable');
    $('#slider-disabled-highlight').slider('disable');
}

App.page.toggle.init = function() {
    console.log("toggle init");
    $('#flip-disabled').slider('disable');
}

App.page.actionBarSample.init = function() {

    var $tabo = $("#tover"),
    overflowState = $tabo.hasClass("noContent");

    $("#left").on("panelbeforeopen", function() {
        //Save the state of the overflow button
        overflowState = $tabo.hasClass("noContent");
        $tabo.addClass("noContent");
    })
    .on("panelbeforeclose", function() {
        //Put the overflow button into the correct state
        if(!overflowState) {
            $tabo.removeClass("noContent");
        }
    });

    //Handle overflow menu clicks
    $(".bb10-panel").bind("vclick", function() {
        //Close the panel
        $(this).panel("close");
    });

    $("#left li").bind("vclick", function() {
        //Clear the active state from any other buttons that may have been set to active
        $(this).siblings().removeClass("ui-btn-active");
        //Add the active state to the selected button
        $(this).addClass("ui-btn-active");
        //Clear the contents of the tab overflow button
        //Add class to put the tab overflow icon in the correct position
        //Clear the active state from all tab buttons in action bar
        $('[data-role="tab"], [data-role="tab-overflow"]').removeClass("active");
    });

    $(".inBar").bind("vclick", function() {
        //Set the active state to the tab in the actionbar
        $('#' + this.id.slice(0, 2)).addClass("active");
        $tabo.addClass("noContent").empty();
        overflowState = true;
    });

    $(".notInBar").bind("vclick", function() {
        //Set the active state to the tab overflow button
        $tabo.empty()
        .addClass("active")
        .html('<img src="img/generic_81_81_placeholder.png" alt=""><p>' + $(this).text() + '</p>')
        .removeClass("noContent");
        overflowState = false;
    });

    $("[data-role='tab']").bind("vclick", function() {
        //Change page on tab click
        if($(this).data("href")) {
            $.mobile.changePage( $(this).data("href"), { transition: "slideup"} );
        }
    });
}

App.page.applicationMenu.init = function() {
    if(typeof blackberry != 'undefined'){
        blackberry.event.addEventListener('swipedown', function(){
            $('#top').panel("open");
        });
        $('#menuBtn').css('display','none');
    }
    else{
        $('#simulInst').css('display','none');
    }
}

App.init();
```

Is App an object specific to Blackberry? I did some dabbling and made a small app but didn't use App or init anything.

Comment: I know nothing about BlackBerry, but the code you provided is standard stuff: Create one object in the global namespace, and then put all properties and methods in there instead of polluting the global namespace. In the code you provided it even calls `App.init()` at the end, so there is probably no magic.

Comment: Is it just a generic object? Where is init() defined?

Comment: App.init() is defined on the third line: `App.init = function () {...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App in this example is defined at the top: 
`App = {};`

So it's just a new plain old JavaScript object (dictionary), which they then define functions and data to it e.g. `App.utils = ...`.

You can try it out on a browser, press <kbd>F12</kbd> and then go to the console (<kbd>ESC</kbd>) and type e.g. `blah = {}` and you will see a new object created with the name blah.  Everything is an object in JavaScript apparently.

### Read more

- http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Comment: Thank you so much. App.utils = function utils(){} Ahh I get it now. New way of defining functions that congused me.

Comment: @RapsFan1981, almost right, e.g. `App.init = function () {` will definie a function that you can call like `App.init();`.  In your code above, `App.utils.metaHack()` was created on a dictionary called utils.

Comment: Oh what I meat was App.utils in JavaScript = function utils(){} in Java right?

Comment: @RapsFan1981, Um, there are two ways in Javascript to define a function, either standalone like `function myFunction() {}` or attached to a variable or object e.g. `myFunction = function(){}`.